# preg_match question

Tags: php, regex

```
$page = $_GET['page'];
if(isset($page))
if(!preg_match('/[\w\d_]+/i', $page)) die("Error");
```

I want to allow alphanum and underscore,

above code works but let say i set 123..., this works too. Is preg_match will not validate behind entry?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regex will match as long as an alphanumeric appears as a substring of `$page`. Since `123...` contains the substring `123` it will pass your regex.

Use

```
/^\w+$/
```

to match the whole string. (`\w` already means `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` so your `\d`, `_` and the `i` modifier are redundant.)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use anchors as:

```
/^\w+$/
```

`\w` already has `\d` and `_`

Comment: And `\w` does already contain uppercase and lowercase variants.